# How to disable suhosin only for a certain directory

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, moodle

I need suhosin disabled for my moodle directory, would putting a .htaccess file disable it only for that directory or would that disable it for the whole site?

Answer (score 1):

An .htaccess file (per-directory Apache config file) applies just to that directory and all child directories. So, yes, in theory, using the appropriate directive in that .htaccess file would disable Suhosin just for that directory.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work... I set a `php_flag suhosin.simulation On` .htaccess file in the root of the moodle directory, then i placed a phpinfo file there suhosin.simulation still off...

Comment: It may be that .htaccess files are not enabled in your server config - you would need to make sure that the `AllowOverride` directive is set appropriately. However, a `<Directory>` section in the server config, as you have done, is preferable to using .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i fixed it with a `<Directory>` attribute.